# Есть ли русский термин для multilabel classification?

Tags: терминология

Читаю документацию по scikit-learn. Там рассматриваются метрики для классификации, и наряду с бинарной и многоклассовой, встречается multilabel. Это что-то типа пересекающихся классов? Понимаю, что вопрос не совсем по теме русского stackoverflow, но, думаю, аудитория подходящая.

Comment: Осилил. Поэтому и спрашиваю, есть ли какой **русский** термин. Или дальше пересекающихся классов не уйти? А может Вы литературу отечественную по этой теме знаете? Или, даже, пример использования подобной классификации приведёте? Уверен, Вам по силам дать хороший, понятный ответ.

Comment: Нечеткая классификация? Вдогонку: если будете с таких козырей заходить, как в предыдущем комментарии, то вам никто помогать не станет.

Comment: А как это связано с `r` или `python`?

Comment: Метки в данном случае для привлечения внимания аудитории, которая точно знакома с этим термином.

Comment: многозначная (политематическая) классификация (результат принадлежит сразу к нескольким категориям, например, как вопросы на Stack Overflow)